# Amazon Video To Chromecast from Android

Tags: android, video, streaming, amazon, chromecast

I'm trying to find any app that can cast the amazon videos to my chromecast. For some strange reason, I have been unable to find such an app. Casting from the browser is ok, but I would like to do this from my android phone. So if have any ideas about any app that can do this please post your answer.